# Django How do I edit a comment

Tags: python, django

how do I edit an existing comment, when a user comment on a post that user can be able to edit his/her comment.

*models.py*

```
class Comments(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
    commented_image = models.ForeignKey(Image, ...) 
    comment_post = models.TextField()
```

*urls.py*

```
path('comments/<id>/', comments, name='comments'),
path('comments/<int:id>/<int:comment_id>', comments, name='comments')
```

*views.py*

```
def comments(request, id, comment_id=None):
    post = get_object_or_404(Image, id=id)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if comment_id:
            edit_form = CommentForm(#codes here) 
        else:
            edit_form = CommentForm(data=request.POST)

        form = CommentForm(request.POST)
        
        if form.is_form():
            comment = form.save(commit=False)
            comment.user = request.user
            comment.commented_image = post
            comment.save()
                return redirect(...)
```

Comment: You pass the comment object to edit through the `instance=` parameter of the `CommentForm(..)` constructor.

Comment: @Willem.. Can you please update your answer with my code

Comment: This is the perfect job to use Django rest framework or tastypie packages depending on what you find easier

Comment: @Ahmed..it is not possible with my code, what should I include?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to pass comment id in the updating function like:

```
path('comment/<int:comment_id>/update' ...
```

and do the following

```
CommentForm(instance=Comment.objects.get(id=comment_id), data=request.POST)
```

UPDATE:
to make the same view handles both create and update
add new URL that point to same view (and place it under the original one):

```
path('comment/<int:id>/<int:comment_id>/', name='comment_update')
```

and update your view like this:

```
def comments(request, id, comment_id=None):
    post = get_object_or_404(Image, id=id)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if comment_id:
            form = CommentForm(instance=Comment.objects.get(id=comment_id), data=request.POST)
        else:
            form = CommentForm(data=request.POST)
    # Rest of your code.
```

and in your template:
if this form is for update:
use `<form method="POST" action="{% url 'comment_update' post.id comment.id %}">`

if it's create form just use:
`<form method="POST" action="{% url 'comment_create' post.id %}">`

Comment: @Ashraf...it worked. Is it possible to do same in comment form? Because I created a new views for edit_comment, I was thinking if I can just execute sane code for comment views also.

Comment: Could you please explain more, do you need the create function to have the ability to update as well?

Comment: @Ashraf...i already have a commentform which takes the ID of my post (Image), that is the view I updated in my question. Now I want to edit an existing comment of a user who commented in my post. Your code works only when I create another views (edit_comment) and passing a comment_id. Is there a way I can edit an existing comment without creating another view(edit_comment) instead of just using one view for posting comment and editing comments. Can you update your answer with my comment views in my question, I think that would be easier.

Comment: Hmmm you can try adding the new url provided in the answer and use the same view, and in the view you can check for the comment_id if it exists def create_comment(request, comment_id=None) .. hope it's clear enough

Comment: I updated my question including your code to it, I get an error 'local variable' edit_form' reference before assignment'. What am I missing here?

Comment: I think you need to name both variables as form

Comment: I got an error reverse for comment_update with arguments (50,") not found. I will update my template in question now

Comment: I don't know why my question didnt update. But passing the id in both the form, I got reverse not found problem. Example; #comment_update form 
    <form method="POST" action={% url 'site:comment_update' post.id comment.id%}>

    #post comment form  
    <form method="POST" action={% url 'site:comments' post.id %}>

Comment: Write your urls

Comment: My url is in my question, please check.

Comment: Did you see my url?

Comment: You are calling comment_update in template while there is no url with this name, change comment_update to comments like the other one

Comment: I am still having same error. With no reverse problem

Comment: I think the problem is here  <form method="POST" action="{% url 'comments' post.id comment.id %}">. Check your code properly, I think there is a problem why I get the reverse error

Comment: I think you didn't write it correctly, i wrote comments as example, bit in your case you should use site:comments because it seems you have a namespace

Comment: Yes i have site as namespace. Please can you update your answer with the full urls and template. As it says reverse is the error here.

Comment: I used <form method="POST" action="{% url 'site:comments' post.id comment.id %}"> or <form method="POST" action="{% url 'site:comments' post.id post.comment_id %}"> none work

Comment: No Reverse Match at/comments/50/ Reverse for 'comments' with arguments '(67, ")' not found. 2 pattern(s) tried: [`comments/(? P<id>[^/] +) /(? P<comment_id>[^/]+) /$',' comments/(? P<id>[^/] +) /$']

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210926/discussion-between-ashraf-emad-and-oghomwen-oguns).

Comment: After all this while learning more on Django, I came back to your answer and I got it working. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Can you provide a screenshot of your page?

```
post = get_object_or_404(Image)
```

why you pass image? it should be your ID that are from I guess your post request.

Comment: @Eyakub...sorry it was a typo, I just corrected my question. Please check